# Convert a direct imperative sentence into indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

Can someone please help me converting this sentence into indirect speech?

> "Go on, have another sweet, Michael" urged Sam.

**Update:** I was thinking along the lines of "*Micheal was ordered by Sam to go on and have some sweets*"

Please accept my apologies as I am new to this community.

Comment: what do you think it should be?

Comment: Please show us your work. What do you think the answer should be, what do you understand to be the difference between direct and indirect speech and what confuses you about it? Us telling you the answer to this specific question won't help you understand the concept of converting between these two types of quotes.

Comment: Apologies, I am new to this community and wasnt aware that we have to attempt an answer by ourselves as well - I have updated my question.

Comment: Do you know what 'indirect speech' is?  It is a way of saying what was said without quoting the speech exactly. "Mary please pass the salt," said Fred. Fred asked Mary to pass the salt.

Comment: Please use the [contact us](/contact) link in order to merge your accounts, so that you can edit your post instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most direct translation into indirect speech:

> Sam urged Michael to go on and have another sweet.

Also, simply:

> Sam urged Michael to have another sweet.

Comment: @YawarMurtaza that's because the question is posted with a different account.

Comment: @Andrew: maybe delete your comment and rewrite it without the first sentence? And delete the response to my comment..

Comment: It's "urged" in the original, so that is the correct verb, but depending on context you could use "ordered", "told", "instructed", "offered", "suggested", "hinted", or a wide range of other "imperative" verbs with varying nuances.